# Azure OAuth2 Code Flow - no groups claim in access token (and no "hasgroups" either)

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, claims

I am using OAuth2 Code flow and trying to get the user's groups back in my access token.  Everything I'm reading says I should see either a groups claim or a hasgroups claim, but I see neither.

I've altered the following fields in the App registration manifest for my client app:

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",
"optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [],
        "accessToken": [
            {
                "name": "groups",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": [
                    "dns_domain_and_sam_account_name"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "saml2Token": []
    },
```

Here is an example of my querystring for the login redirection url (login.microsoftonline.com)...

```
client_id=<clientId>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=<redirectUri>
&response_mode=query
&scope=<appScope>%20offline_access
&state=67890
```

Here is an example of my querystring for my requesting the token using authCode (login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token)

```
client_id=<clientId>
&scope=<uriEncodedScopes>%20offline_access
&redirect_uri=<uriEncodedRedirectUri>
&code=<authCode>
&client_secret=<uriEncodedClientSecret>
&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Everything is working great, but I can't figure out how to get groups info back in my token.

**UPDATE**

I added %20openid to my scope in both urls, and now I'm getting an id_token, but I still don't see "groups" or "hasgroups" in either token.

**UPDATE**

I just added the same manifest changes (groupMembership, optionalClaims) to my API App Registration (instead of my client) - the API that exposes the scope, and I see no change whatsoever.  Access token and Id token don't have any reference to groups at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, it should work. And you just need to configure the `groupMembershipClaims`, `optionalClaims` in your API App Registration, refer to the [reason](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#configuring-optional-claims) below.

[image]

You could refer to my test sample below, I tried with a work account or personal account, both work.

Request the authorization code(the `api://3e013fde-xxxxxxa422f3/User.Test` is my API permission):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://localhost
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid offline_access api://3e013fde-xxxxxxa422f3/User.Test
&state=12345
```

Request the token:

[image]

Decode the token in https://jwt.io/, the `groups` claim is included.

[image]

---

**Note:**

My client App and API App are both created today, I suppose there are may some difference between the app created in the `old App Registration(it is not existing in the portal currently)`, `app registration portal(it has been moved to the new App Registrations)`, `new App Registration(the`App Registration`in portal currently)`.

And from this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#manifest-reference):

[image]

There is also a weird thing during my test, when I create a new API App Registration, just set `"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"` without setting `optionalClaims`, the manifest will be like below.

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",
"optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [],
        "accessToken": [],
        "saml2Token": []
    }
```

Then the `Access token` will not include `groups`, the `ID token` has the `groups`.

If I set it with yours, the `Access token` will have the `groups`.

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",
"optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [],
        "accessToken": [
            {
                "name": "groups",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": [
                    "dns_domain_and_sam_account_name"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "saml2Token": []
    }
```

But when I set it return to

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",
"optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [],
        "accessToken": [],
        "saml2Token": []
    }
```

The `Access token` still has the `groups`.

From the portal - `Token configuration (preview)` and this doc - `Configure group claims for applications with Azure Active Directory (Public Preview)`, the feature should be in preview, it may be a bug(I am not sure).

**So in conclusion, I recommend you to use two new Apps to have a try.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can't try it currently because I need my admin to increase our spending limit on this test account, but in the meantime - what is your level of Azure AD?  I was using the default (free) version.  Do I need to upgrade to the Premium version of AD?  I'm curious if I need to configure the "Users and Groups" in my client App Registration to add my groups there.

Comment: @TimHardy I am also using AAD free version. And I think it is no need to add your groups in the SP(enterprise app) -> `Users and Groups`, just make sure Properties -> User assignment required -> `No`. **The best way to test my solution is to create two new Apps**, because there be a bug that I can't reproduce.

Comment: I was finally able to get my Azure workspace back online.  After re-creating the api app registration, I started seeing the groups in my tokens.  Thanks for the help.